# Book series about a woman (possibly a jinn) cast down to Earth, and people with elemental powers

Tags: story-identification, books, urban-fantasy

This book series, I remember being a trilogy. There was this woman who I believe was a jinn, or something.

She was cast down to Earth and she had to 'connect' with this man, who had earth powers or similar in order to survive. This man and his wife are then killed and she moved in with the guy's brother in order to attempt to find that daughter of the first guy after she goes missing.

There are authorities who know about these powers and I remember them being a fairly common concept. The daughter is then experimented on by an old friend of the cast-out woman, and develops powers earlier than she is supposed to.

I believe it is the second book where the cast-out woman contacts some old friends who tell her that the entity running the 'camp' is someone she damaged immensly who is very powerful and killed at least two known jinns.

In the last book I remember a sort of camp, where children are trained and exploited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the ***[Outcast Season](https://www.goodreads.com/series/45938-outcast-season)*** series by Rachel Caine.

- Book 1: *[Undone](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3596225-undone)* (2008)
- Book 2: *[Unknown](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6582703-unknown)* (2010)
- Book 3: *[Unseen](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8182700-unseen)* (2011)
- Book 4: *[Unbroken](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8495990-unbroken)* (2012)

The Goodreads summary for the first book notes that Cassiel was once a powerful Djinn, who was then forced to live among mortals, some of whom are Weather Wardens. She earned her keep by assisting an Earth Warden, and developed feelings for his brother.

> **Once she was a powerful Djinn. Then Cassiel defied her ruler, Ashan, who tore her very essence away and reshaped her in human flesh as punishment. Forced to live among mortals, Cassiel has found refuge among the Weather Wardens**--whose power she must tap into regularly, or she will die.
>
> **Cassiel earns her keep by assisting the Earth Warden Manny Rocha on his missions--which she finds much easier than coping with the emotions and frailties of her human condition, especially her growing affection for Manny's brother, Luis.** But when Cassiel encounters a malevolent force that threatens the Rocha family, she discovers that her perceived human weakness may be her greatest strengths...

The summary for the third book mentions that another female Djinn has been capturing and indoctrinating children from around the world, so she can use their power for herself.

> **After Cassiel and Warden Luis Rocha rescue an adept child from a maniacal Djinn, they realize two things: the girl is already manifesting an incredible amount of power, and her kidnapping was not an isolated incident.**
>
> **This Djinn—aided by her devoted followers—is capturing children all over the world, and indoctrinating them so she can use their strength for herself.** With no other options, Cassiel infiltrates the Djinn’s organization—because if Cassiel cannot stop the Djinn’s apocalyptic designs, all of humanity may be destroyed.

The books are apparently set in the same universe as Caine's earlier *[Weather Warden](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40609-weather-warden)* series.